# My ConstraintLayout doesn't appear in my blueprints

Tags: java, android, textview, android-constraintlayout

By default, when i create an empty activity, Android Studio added to this activity a ConstraintLayout ad a TextView. Now the problem is that i can't view this component, but when i start my app, the TextView magically appear. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: there's nothing "magical" about it. Your computer might have little RAM so it can't (or won't try to) render the preview as this is a memory-expensive process.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SDK version 28 or android-P, then It's a bug in Android Studio with the latest SDK. Most probably they will fix it in next update.